# UseRef issue in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect

**Example** is a functional component. I am using `useRef()` hook to get the **ref** a div element. I want to **attach** an event listener to the **ref** when **Example** mounts.

```
const Example: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClick = (): void => {
    // mouse click logic
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref && ref.current) {
      ref.current.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }

    return (): void => {
      if (ref && ref.current) {
        ref.current.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} />
  );
};
```

What's happening is that the **ref** is still null when **Example** did mount. So, I am unable to attach `event listener` to it. An **alternative solution** would be to assign an `id` to div and attach event listener to the DOM node directly **which I don't** really want to do.

Any **guidance** on how can I attach event listener to the **ref** will be really helpful :)

Comment: What's the reason for using a ref to add a click listener? Does an `onClick` prop not suffice?

Comment: The way you have used is correct. Adding a working snippet: 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kkqwwd 

Can you create a demo for the issue you are getting?

Comment: @NicholasTower because it's not a good practice to pass onClick prop to non-interactive elements.

Comment: `because it's not a good practice to pass onClick prop to non-interactive elements.` Say's who? Refs are an escape hatch for the things that react can't do declaratively. But react *can* do click listeners declaratively, so you should do so.

Comment: @NicholasTower you can check here: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md

Comment: The fix for that is to use a more descriptive tag than a `<div>` or to add a `role` attribute. By using a ref, the only thing you're accomplishing is making the code so hard to follow that the linter can't tell that you're making a mistake. But you're still making the same mistake: the element is still interactive, and still lacks a role.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for such a wonderful guidance..!

Comment: Hi guys, can someone answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428958/react-js-how-to-animate-conditionally-rendered-components ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onClick` to set the event.

```
const Example = () => {
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    // mouse click logic
  }, [])

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>Hello World</div>
  );
};
```

But if you would wanted to use the ref  you need to understand fine some concepts. Firstly I have tested your code and the ref is ready when the `useEffect` is executed because the `useEffect` is executed after the DOM is drawn.

Secondly you need to understand the hook's dependencies because in your code the `handleClick` is created in each render but the useEffect is using the first reference created of this function so you can have problems if you use dependencies inside `handleClick`

Finally, I recommend you to invest `useCallback, useState, useRef, useEffect` and `useReducer` to know the differences and the best situations for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a ref for this. React supports click events out of the box using the standard declarative syntax.

```
const Example: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClick = (): void => {
    // mouse click logic
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick} />
  );
};
```

You mentioned in the comments that the reason you tried doing this was to silence a lint rule. But using a ref doesn't fix the problem that the linter is pointing out, it just makes the code complicated enough that the linter can't figure out what you're doing, and so doesn't realize that your code has the same problem as before.

To fix the lint issue, add a role attribute to the div so that screenreaders know what the purpose of this div is. Exactly which role to use depends on what the click handler is doing, but the most likely roles are probably "button" or "link".

```
return (
  <div onClick={handleClick} role="button" />
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that information. Can you help me with as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428958/react-js-how-to-animate-conditionally-rendered-components ?