# React JS: How to animate conditionally rendered components?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions, conditional-rendering

**Example** is a functional component in which I am rendering a `div` conditionally. I want this `div` to **fade-in** when rendered conditionally and **fade-out** vice versa.

For that, I have maintained two local state variables: `render` and `fadeIn` which are computed based on `show` prop passed down to the **Example** component.

**What I've done is:**

- When `show` prop it **true**, I set `render` as **true**, so the `div` renders conditionally and after a timeout of `10ms` I set `fadeIn`  as **true** which will set CSS classname for my div as `show`.
- When `show` prop it **false**, I set `fadeIn` as **false**, which will set CSS classname for my div as `hide` and after a timeout of `200ms` (transition time in CSS) I set `render`  as **false** so the `div` is hidden conditionally.

**Code:**

```
interface Props {
  show: boolean;
}

const Example: React.FC<Props> = ({ show, }) => {
  const [render, setRender] = useState(false);
  const [fadeIn, setFadeIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      // render component conditionally
      setRender(show);

      // change state to for conditional CSS classname which will
      // animate opacity, I had to give a timeout of 10ms else the
      // component shows up abruptly
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFadeIn(show);
      }, 10);
    } else {
      // change state to change component classname for opacity animation
      setFadeIn(false);

      // hide component conditionally after 200 ms
      // because that's the transition time in CSS
      setTimeout(() => {
        setRender(false);
      }, 200);
    }
  }, [
    show,
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {render && (
        <div className={`container ${fadeIn ? 'show' : 'hide'}`} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Stylesheet:**

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I believe this is **not a good coding practice** to achieve the functionality and should maintain only one local state in my component. I need your **suggestions** on how I can solve this in a **better way** **without using any 3rd Party Library**.
Thanks :)

Comment: You should checkout React Transition Group. It basically solves what you're trying to do with a really clean API. https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Comment: @StephanOlsen thanks, but I don't want to integrate any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 4):

```
const [render, setRender] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   if(show) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       setRender(true);
     }, 2000);
   } else {
     setRender(false);
   }
}, [show]);

<div className={cs(s.render, render ? 'show' : undefined)}>
  <p>{content}</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.render {
  ...,
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope be helpful.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate a little, I'm struggling with understanding **cs** in `<div className={cs(s.render, render ? 'show' : undefined)}>`?

Comment: cs stands for classnames package in npm,Its a utility for conditionally joining classNames together ** import cs from 'classnames'; **

Comment: In your example you can just add classes globally and the styles will apply as well. but with this package you can style in your component css or sass file and just effect on that component.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that but setting visibility to hidden won't really solve my problem. Because the element in still present in DOM, which is quite unnecessary for my use case.

Comment: Now I got you, let me try and test

Comment: refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064249/react-animate-mount-and-unmount-of-a-single-component

Comment: actually, it is not a conditional rendering, it is a conditional visibility

Comment: @MichaelYurin ya thats why I shared a link

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a HTML attribute for this situationes called `onAnimationEnd` or `onAnimationStart` based on your case.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => {
        setIsMounted(!isMounted)
        if (!showDiv) setShowDiv(true); //We should Render our Div
      }
      }>Show/Hide</button>

      { //Conditional Rendering
        showDiv && <div
        className="transitionDiv"
        style={isMounted ? mountedStyle : unmountedStyle}
        onAnimationEnd={() => { if (!isMounted) setShowDiv(false) }}
      ></div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

More info can be found in this [article](https://dev.to/oussel/how-to-use-conditional-rendering-with-animation-in-react-1k20)

Comment: Very nice! Never knew about that one