# Smooth animation when turning off a conditionally rendered component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, conditional-rendering

My App.js is as below

```
export const App = () => {
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
  const [ordering, setOrdering] = useState(false);

  const handleColorModeClick = () => {
    setToggled((s) => !s);
  };

  const handleOrdering = () => {
    setOrdering((s) => !s);
  };

  return (
    <Ordering.Provider value={{ ordering: ordering }}>
      <div className={`app ${toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"}`}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <HeaderComponent toggled={toggled} onClick={handleColorModeClick} />
            <div>components2</div>
            <EateryInfo toggled={toggled} />
            {/* <CategoryItems toggled={toggled} /> */}
            <MenuButton toggled={toggled} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/menu">
            <HeaderComponent toggled={toggled} onClick={handleColorModeClick} />
            <CategoryItems toggled={toggled} />
            <CheckBox
              text="Start Ordering"
              standAlone={true}
              handleOrdering={handleOrdering}
            />
            <MenuButton toggled={toggled} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Ordering.Provider>
  );
};
```

I set the state of `ordering` variable using a checkbox

Then I use this to conditionally render the `QuantityChange` component like so

```
export const MenuEntry = ({ mealData, toggled }: MenuEntryProps) => {
  const orderingEnabled = useContext(Ordering);

  return (
    <div className="menu-entry">
      <MenuItem oneMenuItem={mealData} toggled={toggled} />
      {orderingEnabled.ordering ? <QuantityChange toggled={toggled} /> : ""}
    </div>
  );
};
```

All this works fine & the component is render as desired.

I want to have a smooth transition of entry & exit of this component. The animation on entry works just fine but I am not able to figure out how to get the exit animation working.

The video is what is happening now can be found in the video here https://youtu.be/5kl1wCBwR_U (the checkbox is at the right bottom hand corner)

I looked at several online forums to find an answer to this but I am unable to figure it out.

I tried usiing `react-transition-group` as well but no luck

```
export const QuantityChange = ({ toggled }: QuantityChangeProps) => {
  const orderingEnabled = useContext(Ordering);
  const duration = 500;
  return (
    <Transition in={orderingEnabled.ordering} timeout={duration} appear>
      {(status) => (
        <div
          className={`quantity-change flex ${
            toggled ? "theme-dark" : "theme-light"
          } fade-${status}`}
        >
          <span className="add-quantity">+</span>
          <span className="quantity">0</span>
          <span className="subtract-quantity">-</span>
        </div>
      )}
    </Transition>
  );
};
```

I looked at `onAnimationEnd` but was unable to figure it out.

Comment: You could try out to have a css class that does the animation and then adding useEffect with cleanup part (`return () => doStuff()`) that would get triggered before component will unmount and you could use setTimeout within this cleanup function that would set this css class

Comment: @JSEvgeny I think you are referring to something like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428958/react-js-how-to-animate-conditionally-rendered-components I tried that & it does not work. The reason is that the state change in happening on the `checkBox` and the animation has to happen on a separate component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a simple Accordion thingy.
You could try something like that (snippet below).

One of the main moments here is setting the `height` to the `auto` value. It allows the content to change, and it won't strict its dimensions.

`AccordionItem` conditionally renders its children. If it should be closed and the animation is over, then no children will be rendered.

```js
const AccordionItem = (props) => {
  const { className, headline, open, children } = props

  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0)
  const [isOver, setOver] = React.useState(false)
  const bodyRef = React.useRef(null)

  const getDivHeight = React.useCallback(() => {
    const { height } = bodyRef.current ? bodyRef.current.getBoundingClientRect() : {}

    return height || 0
  }, [])

  // set `auto` to allow an inner content to change
  const handleTransitionEnd = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.propertyName === 'height') {
        setHeight(open ? 'auto' : 0)
        if (!open) {
          setOver(true)
        }
      }
    },
    [open]
  )

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(getDivHeight())
    setOver(false)
    
    if (!open) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => setHeight(0))
      })
    }

  }, [getDivHeight, open])
  
  const shouldHide = !open && isOver

  return (
    <div style={{overflow: 'hidden'}}>
      <div
        style={{ height, transition: "all 2s" }}
        onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
      >
        <div ref={bodyRef}>
          {shouldHide ? null : children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}



const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <div>          
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)}>toggle</button>
      
      <table style={{width: '100%'}}>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Hot Pongal
            <AccordionItem open={open}>
              <button>-</button>
              <input  />
              <button>+</button>
             </AccordionItem> 
          </td>
          <td>
            Hot Pongal
            <AccordionItem open={open}>
              <button>-</button>
              <input  />
              <button>+</button>
             </AccordionItem> 
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            Hot Pongal
            <AccordionItem open={open}>
              <button>-</button>
              <input  />
              <button>+</button>
             </AccordionItem> 
          </td>
          <td>
            Hot Pongal
            <AccordionItem open={open}>
              <button>-</button>
              <input  />
              <button>+</button>
             </AccordionItem> 
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            Hot Pongal
            <AccordionItem open={open}>
              <button>-</button>
              <input  />
              <button>+</button>
             </AccordionItem> 
          </td>
          <td>
            Hot Pongal
            <AccordionItem open={open}>
              <button>-</button>
              <input  />
              <button>+</button>
             </AccordionItem> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Updated my snippet. Now the `AccordionItem` conditionally renders its children. If it should be closed and the animation is over, then no children will be rendered.

Comment: Ivan, even in your code, only entry of the children in automated, the exit is however, abrupt. I want the exit to be also smooth.

Comment: Ah, hold on... looks like it doesn't for as it should in Chrome. Let me fix it.

Comment: @moys, it's done. I had to wrap the "closing part" to extra `requestAnimationFrame` cuz Chrome and Safari manage the order of a script calling differently a bit.